# perl avoiding of the "HTML Generation function"

Tags: perl

The avoiding of the "HTML Generation functions" doesnt work for me.
If I start on my localhost the perlscript

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print '<html>';
print '<head>';
print '<title>Hello Perl</title>';
print '</head>';
print '<body>';
print '<h2>Hello perl</h2>';
print '</body>';
print '</html>';
```

My browser print it out as expected:

"Hello perl"

But perldoc advices: "HTML Generation functions should no longer be used".
 So I tried the object oriented cgitutorial-script (perl, v5.10.0).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI; 
$q = new CGI; 
print $q->header,
$q->start_html('hello world'), 
$q->h1('hello world'), 
$q->end_html;
```

The browser shows
 

 
"Internal Server Error"

If I load the above script on the terminal with

```
$perl mycgi.pl
```

it shows an expected outcome

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the extra little `t` in there for?

Comment: What really is meant with [_HTML Generation functions should no longer be used_](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-4.37/lib/CGI.pod#HTML_Generation_functions_should_no_longer_be_used) is: don't use CGI functions like `$q->start_html(...)` at all. These are the functions generating HTML. ;-) Have a look at the [Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.15/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm) to CGI, such as [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) or [Dancer2](http://perldancer.org/) or [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/). Once you start with them, you'll love it. Promised.

Comment: Your first script writes HTML directly. That's _not_ using the HTML generation functions. The second one uses them. I would prefer the first version, but it's still ugly. I suggest you watch [this lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s) by SawyerX.

Comment: I dont got any usefull answer to my problem, but thanks Perlduck for the Explikation about the cgi policy and the "HTML Generation functions should no longer be used".

Comment: If you get an "internal server error" message in your browser, then there will be more information about the error in your web server error log. Without knowing what it says in there, we would just be guessing at the cause of your problem - and that would be a waste of everyone's time. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47356896/edit) to add the messages from the error log.

Comment: Thanks for that. The log says: "(8)Exec format error: exec of '/Library/WebServer/perling/mycgi.pl' failed"

Comment: @StephenSt: Important information like that can get lost in if it's put in comments. Why not [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47356896/edit) and put it up there?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment:

> (8)Exec format error: exec of '/Library/WebServer/perling/mycgi.pl' failed

That usually indicates a problem with your shebang line. Is the shebang on the first line of your program? Does it point to an executable that really exists? Are there spurious invisible characters at the end of the line (this is sometimes the case when a program is written on Windows and run on a Unix system).

Comment: The codes are listet on my thread above. But how I sad, from the command line comes an expected outcome. It is the browser site that doesn't load the code from the mycgi.pl.

Comment: @StephenSt: Of course, running your code as `perl mycgi,pl` won't use the shebang line. So you're just strengthening my theory that there is something wrong with it. If you were to answer my other questions, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: That's embarrassing, sorry. It was a space on begin of the shebang line. Neverless, thank you for your patience.